# Which regex condition could I use in to capture a math formula with units in R?

Tags: r, regex, mathml, odf

I am looking at codes in odf formulas that look a bit like  this:
{500mgl} over {4.05grams}
[image: Example]

I want to use a regex with gsub in R to enclose in brackets all of the elements with the pattern

```
([0-9]+)([A-Za-z]+)
```

to avoid some units not displaying in the denominator.
However, if I do this, the respective units will end up separated from the
real number: 4,{0.5g}
So what I want to enclose first the numbers with the commas:

```
a<-"4,05g"
gsub("([0-9]+)(\\,)([0-9]+)([A-Za-z]+)","{\\1\\2\\3\\4}",a)
```

and then, enclose with brackets the pattern:

```
([0-9]+)([A-Za-z]+)
```

but only if there is not an opening bracket before the pattern.
I've tried searching the web for how look back syntax works with regex, however, I get pretty confused with how it works within R's gsub.
I tried things like this:

```
gsub("([^\\.])([0-9]+)([A-Za-z]+)","{\\2\\3}",a)
gsub("(?[\\.])([0-9]+)([A-Za-z]+)","{\\2\\3}",a)
gsub("(!\\.?)([0-9]+)([A-Za-z]+)","{\\2\\3}",a)
```

but honestly I have no idea what I'm doing.

EDIT: I think that the exemption for the previous character must be not a bracket but a comma. That way one would avoid the output

```
"0,3g
" 0,{3g}"
```

but be able to do

```
"30g"
"{30g}"
```

Comment: Great effort verbally describing what you want. However, having read it a few times I'm not sure what the expected output looks like. Could you add a specific input and expected output? Is it from `"(500mg"/"L* 10.00) over 4,05"` to `"(500mg)/(L*10.00) over (4,05)"`?

Comment: it's like in the picture, in the third line where the code is. I want to enclose in brackets whole numbers with units {12g} and enclose numbers with decimals {12,4g} the problem is that enclosing whole numbers without the exception of the previous bracket, would leave the number out of its decimal part {4,{2g}} it would be like in your example but with brackets instead of parenthesis. however, if I select only patterns with commas, I won't enclose whole numbers with it's respective unit

Comment: I am not sure if this is what your are looking for, but have you tried to make the comma optional? You can use `,?` to do that.
The whole regex then would look like this:
`a<-c("4,05g", "50mg", "120,32mg"); gsub("(\\d+,?\\d+\\w+)", "{\\1}", a)`.

Comment: yes @Cett That I think works for my intentions. Hadn't thought of it as a whole pattern. G ood idea. I'll try it tomorrow on the PC when I get to work

Comment: See https://ideone.com/8AOgQM. ``\d+,?\d+\w+`` is a wrong pattern here as it will not let you match single digit numbers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you. Of course you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```r
x <- "4,05g"
gsub("(\\d+(?:,\\d+)?[[:alpha:]]*)", "{\\1}", x)
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/8AOgQM) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6pQgis/2).

*Details*:

- `(` - Group 1 start (necessary as `gsub` does not support backreferences to the whole match):

  - `\d+`  - one or more digits
  - `(?:,\d+)?` - an optional sequence of a comma and one or more digits
  - `[[:alpha:]]*` - zero or more letters
- `)` - end of the group.

The `\1` in the replacement is the value of Group 1.